# incorrect element positioning

Tags: html, css, positioning

The first time I go to [this page](http://www.iol.ie/~murtaghd/stef/index.html), the positioning of the slideshow (developed using the JQuery cycle plugin) is all messed up, like this:

[image: bad layout]

If I then refresh the page, it displays correctly, like this:

[image]

How can I ensure that this page displays correctly the first time it's viewed? The incorrect layout seems to happen more often with Chrome than with other browsers, though as you can see from the screenshots above it also happens with other browsers.

Thanks,
Don

Comment: I have seen your site but not getting issue.. :(

Comment: can you try using chrome if you have it?

Answer (score 2):

Add `width` and `height` attributes to the images.

I'm guessing that the JavaScript activates before the image is loaded, it then does a couple quick computations to get the dimensions it needs, and locks them in place; all of this happens before the image is loaded and since there are no `width` or `height` attributes, the dimensions come out way off. On the reload, the image comes out of the browser cache so the dimensions are known when the JavaScript runs.

Your JavaScript runs when the DOM is ready, not when every single thing has been fully resolved and loaded. You could also try binding your slideshow to the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event rather than `document.ready`.

You see this in Chrome more than other browsers because Chrome is really fast and that magnifies the timing issue.